# How to use find with globs in a Bash shell script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, globstar

I'm trying to use `find` with *globs* in a Bash shell script. I've tried to both sourcing it and running it, but the command fails every time.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# glob-test.sh - a script to test globs in find
cd /to/a/windows/share-point
find ./**/*Some/*Place/**/ -iname "*.pdf"

# How about using foreign characters?
find ./**/*Söme/*Pläce/**/ -iname "*.pdf"
```

- From bash command line it works
- I have tried different way of quoting it.
- I have tried *sourcing* and *executing* the script.
- I have tried turning on/off the *globstar* shell option, both inside and outside the script, but still no go. (`shopt -s/u globstar`)

What is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Please can you explain (in your question) what you mean by "_fails every time_". Error? Nothing appears? (What should appear?) Unexpected results appear? A test scenario you can use to explain this would help too

Comment: Is it actually a bash script? How are you running it? What's the shebang?

Comment: LIke I said, I tried running as either. Shebang: `#!/usr/bin/env bash` with `./script.sh` or using `. script.sh` for sourcing. Fails meaning, it says it can's find any files, while everything is found when just copy pasting this into shell.

Comment: Please put that into your question, so that it remains the definitive place for your issue and all its detail

Comment: I just tested at home, and it works here. The issue was at work. I will test there tomorrow. It's possible its an issue when searching on windows shares...

Comment: Does `echo ./**/*Some/*Place/**/` output the intended list?

Comment: The problem had mainly to do with foreign character sets in the search string, not shown above. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem that the issue was 2-fold,

- When doing this on a windows share-point, and **sourcing** it, `find` returns *very* slowly, the *first* time. But much faster the *second* time. Somehow there must be some kind of buffering/cache'ing going on. So the user thinks that the command failed or blocked. This is not the case when executing. As sourcing is run in the current shell, `globstar` probably need to be enabled. Running it as a script seem to not have this issue and also seem to be independent of the *globstar* setting.
- The result of above, is that somehow the character set also confused *find* when running as a script vs. sourced. Running sourced would use the locally set character set of the terminal which is correct, while scripted, would use that of the default/OS, AFAICT. (I work in 3 different languages.)

What I did not know or tell in OP, is that I was using another language characters (containing umlauts) in the `/*Some/*Place/` part. I didn't think it would matter, but it caused the command to fail. As it secretly was searching for the 2-byte UTF-8 characters, while correctly displaying only one.

I'm not completely sure what is going on under the bash hood here, but fiddling with the character sets, and patienly wait for the results, I got it to work as expected. Feel free to post a better or more clear answer.